# Find latest record in employee list

Tags: c#, linq

Hi Below is the record set I'm having.

```
------------------
Emp#        Date
------------------
emp1        09/12/2015
emp1        09/13/2015
emp2        09/11/2015
emp3        09/10/2015
emp4        09/14/2015
emp3        09/11/2015
emp2        09/14/2015
```

I need a linq statement, with output as below.

```
------------------
Emp#        Date
------------------
emp1        09/13/2015
emp2        09/14/2015
emp3        09/11/2015
emp4        09/14/2015
```

Basically, get the latest single record per employee. My Input is employee ID's as list.

I tried all the combinations but nothing helps me. Kindly help me, as I've more than 100k records and 5k employees with different date.

I need to retrieve all with a single call to DB.

Comment: var punchedJobs =
        (GetAllAsQueryable()
          .Where(
            punch =>
                employeeIDs.Contains(punch.Employee.ID))
                );
      punchedJobs;    after this I'm iterating tru for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.EmpId)
                 .Select(x => new 
                              {
                                  EmpId = x.Key,
                                  Date = x.OrderByDescending(z => z.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date
                              };
```

Or, in query syntax:

```
from emp in employees
group emp by emp.Id into g
let date = g.Select(e => e.Date).OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault();
select new {id = g.Key, date};
```

Comment: basically I'm doing from DB GetAllAsQueryable(). so if I did groupby then its more records. Also its a smaple where i mention emp# and date, but actually emp table has more than 20 fields. Then how to do it in better way?

Comment: If you want the records by same criteria i.e. the latest record for each employee, then as suggested by @dcastro, in the `date` variable you will have the first object within each group, you can use that to access other properties like this: `select new {id = g.Key, date = date.date, prop1 = date.prop1 , ...and so on};`